# Update query not working in Vb.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

i am trying to update the database using update but for some reason database is not getting updated
i used following query:

```
Dim dc As OleDbCommand
dc = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE tempM1 SET [input] = '" & ans_selected & "' WHERE question = '" & question & "'", cn)
dc.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

i am using 1 more update query and its working fine:

```
dc = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE tempTof SET [input] = '" & optionSelected & "' WHERE question = '" & question & "'", cn)
dc.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

please help... i wasted almost 2 hours figuring out whats wrong but couldnt debug it.

Comment: Check the value of `question` and make sure it corresponds to an actual row in your table.

Comment: i tried replacing value of question with actual value from database but still there some problem. The query gets executed but the value of ans_selected is not inserted in table, instead value of row is updated to NONE

Comment: these are two different tables.
first one is tempM1 and second is tempTof

Comment: have you made sure that there is definitely a value assigned to ans_selected?

Answer (score 0):

You should always use parametrized query, also I don't see in your code where you open the connection

```
Dim cn As OleDbConnection
Using(cn = GetConnection())
    cn.Open();
    Dim dc As OleDbCommand 
    dc = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE tempM1 SET [input] = ? WHERE question = ?", cn) 
    dc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ans", ans_selected)
    dc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@question", question)
    dc.ExecuteNonQuery() 
End Using
```

Comment: actully i had already opend the connection in begining and forget to show it here in code...
well i tried the method suggested by you Steve, but still the value of column [input] is not being updated in database by ans_selected, instead value of [input] column is NONE

Comment: Your columns [input] and question are of type Text? I suppose so because you have enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: problem fixed... actully i decclared ans_selected inside the function, and it was taking default value, i declared it as global variable and the problem was fixed!! thanx anyways.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim dc As OleDbCommand
dc = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE tempM1 SET [input] = '" & ans_selected & "' WHERE question = '" & question & "'", cn)
```

> ### put something in here to examine dc.CommandText such as:
>
> ```
> Console.WriteLine dc.CommandText
> ```

```
dc.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Does dc.CommandText really contain what you expect it to contain?

If it does, and it says something like

```
UPDATE tempM1 SET [input]='foo' WHERE question='bar'
```

Then double check by going direct to the database and checking that substituting the UPDATE for a SELECT returns at least one row:

```
SELECT * FROM tempM1 WHERE question='bar'
```

If all those steps are satisfactory and you're still stuck:

1. Double check the connectionstring is truly pointing to the same database you think it is.
2. Bypass your code and execute the UPDATE command yourself directly in the underlying database and check that's being allowed.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to follow process of your SQL Query.
For example:

```
Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\UCC\Desktop\database.mdb") ' Access Database
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandText = "update student set sname=@sname, scity=@scity where ID=@ID"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sname", TextBox2.Text) ' Name
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scity", TextBox3.Text) ' City Text
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", TextBox1.Text) ' ID text

        conn.Open() ' opening connection
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() ' executing non Query
        conn.Close() ' Closing the connection
```

In above code, If your query has `sname` as first and `scity` as second and `ID` as third. Then You have to pass Parameters by following structure. If  `sname` is first then you have to pass `@sname` as first parameter. Otherwise you'll get error.